# prevent GridBagLayout from resizing columns

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

Another problem with swing. How can I stop GridBagLayout from respacing components if one of them changes size? For example, I have few columns, in one of which there is a JLabel with text "text". When I change it to "texttext" layout manager resizes the whole column. I don't want it to do that. Is there any way to prevent it?

Example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class ResizeIssue {

 static int value = 99;

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    final JLabel valueLabel = new JLabel(String.valueOf(value));
    JButton decButton = new JButton("-");
    decButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            valueLabel.setText(String.valueOf(--value));
        }
    });

    JButton incButton = new JButton("+");
    incButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            valueLabel.setText(String.valueOf(++value));
        }
    });

  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
  GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
  c.weightx = 1;
  c.gridx = 0;
  c.gridy = 0;
  panel.add(decButton, c);
  c.gridx = 1;
  panel.add(valueLabel, c);
  c.gridx = 2;
  panel.add(incButton, c);

  frame.add(panel);
  frame.pack();
  frame.setVisible(true);
  }
 }
```

It is visible while 9 -> 10 or anytime text changes width.

Comment: for better help sooner edit your question with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), demonstrated your issue with resize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GridBagLayout ignores maximumWidth/Height. There's not an easy way to set the maximum size of the JLabel.

But, what I think you really want is the layout to not shift when the text in the JLabel changes.

That can be done by making the JLabel wide enough to hold the largest value it needs to display. For example:

```
    jLabel1.setFont(new Font("monospace", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    FontMetrics fm = jLabel1.getFontMetrics(jLabel1.getFont());
    int w = fm.stringWidth("0000");
    int h = fm.getHeight();
    Dimension size = new Dimension(w, h);
    jLabel1.setMinimumSize(size);
    jLabel1.setPreferredSize(size);
```

**Update:**

To center the label text, just add:

```
    jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
```

Comment: This only partially solves the problem, because if I do so, text is not centered in space between buttons (if 'the mask' is xx, one-digit number is 9x, x is not visible, but takes space).

Comment: @update: gosh, didn't think about it and it worked in this case. I still have similar situation with long text, but with that button still moves a bit.

Comment: @joval It just comes down to sizing the JLabel such that it doesn't need to grow to accommodate the text you will be displaying. If you have no control of the text, then switch up to a JTextArea in a JScrollPane

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ResizeIssue2 {
  static int value = 99;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    final JLabel valueLabel = new JLabel(String.valueOf(value));
    JButton decButton = new JButton("-");
    decButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            valueLabel.setText(String.valueOf(--value));
        }
    });

    JButton incButton = new JButton("+");
    incButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            valueLabel.setText(String.valueOf(++value));
        }
    });

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    panel.add(decButton, c);
    c.gridx = 1;
    panel.add(valueLabel, c);
    c.gridx = 2;
    panel.add(incButton, c);

    //*
    c.gridy = 1; 
    int w = 32; //incButton.getPreferredSize().width;
    for(c.gridx=0;c.gridx<3;c.gridx++) {
      panel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(w), c);
    }
    // */

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, button-label-button is only a part of my dialog, have four rows like and one similar under these so I cannot add anything under. Tried on similar block, but doesn't work.